# How do you SELECT from Two Tables in MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

I have two MySql tables which I need to select a column from one, and where the results are used to select from another table. I know how to do it as two different select statements. However, I believe I can do it as a single statement but have no idea how.

Table one has two columns the second column has values which are also found in table two. I need to select all rows in table two which has the same values as those found in table one and where another column value is 0.

Any ideas how to go about doing this?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you familiar with inner joins? Since you've only asked about querying the tables and haven't shown any code, what does [tag:c#] have to do with the question?

Comment: please add your table structure or that column which has same value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySql inner join and "OR" if value equals 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33114570/mysql-inner-join-and-or-if-value-equals-0)

Comment: Try to use  Join query .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Join On tables to get columns form both table using query as

```
 SELECT column_list 
 FROM table_1 
 LEFT JOIN table_2 ON 
 table_1.column = table_2.column;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use  Join query

```
SELECT columns  
FROM table1   
INNER JOIN table2  
ON table1.column = table2.column;
```